# Replace text using Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, text, replace

I am attempting to replace text from a source file into a new file.
The replacing of text works for one line, but a few lines down and I fail to replace text sitting in the middle of a statement.

Here is the source text. The words in brackets are what I am trying to replace, without changing the characters around the words:

```
[set interfaces] ge-0/0/0 [description] "OoB Mgmt Connection"
```

This is what I would like to output:

`interface x/x name"xxx"` (also adding quotations for the xxx text after "name")

Edit:

However the output text replaces once, but then keeps copies of the original text:

```
    set interfaces ge-0/0/0 description "OoB Mgmt Connection"
    set interfaces ge-0/0/0 description "OoB Mgmt Connection"
    interface 1/1 name "OoB Mgmt Connection"
    set interfaces ge-0/0/0 enable
    set interfaces ge-0/0/0 enable
    interface 1/1 enable 
    set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 description "EX4300-mgmt-1;10.30.41.14;ge-0/0/6\\n"
    set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 description "EX4300-mgmt-1;10.30.41.14;ge-0/0/6\\n"
```

Here is my code:

```
    with open("SanitizedFinal_E4300.txt", "rt") as fin:
         with open("output6.txt", "wt") as fout:
              for line in fin:
                  fout.write(line.replace('set system host-name EX4300', 'hostname "EX4300"'))
                  fout.write(line.replace('set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet address', 'ip address'))
```

Please let me know where I went wrong or if there is a better way of approaching this.
I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: You're telling python to replace the literal text `set interfaces ge- description `.  Does that actual text appear in the file?

Comment: "I fail to replace text sitting in the middle of a statement" Could you post the statement where your code failed @sammysosa

Comment: If you're replacing three separate strings, then you need three separate replace statements.  `line.replace('set interfaces','').replace('ge-','').replace('description','name')`.

Comment: Are you trying to turn `[set interfaces] ge-0/0/0 [description] "OoB Mgmt Connection"` into `interface 0/0/0  name"OoB Mgmt Connection"`? If that's the case, something along the lines of `line.replace("[set interfaces] ge-", "interface ").replace("[description] ", "name ")` should work.

Comment: Your input text does not match your output text.   Your loop is clearly wrong, since you are writing two lines for every input line.  Please show us the entire input file, and the entire output file you would like to get.  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using regular expressions, i.e. re.sub() (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub). In your example this snipped should work:

```
import re

fixed_line = re.sub(r'\[set interfaces\] ge-([^ ]*)[^"]*("[^"]*")',
       r'interface \1 name \2',
       '[set interfaces] ge-0/0/0 [description] "OoB Mgmt Connection"'
       )
```

where:
r'[set interfaces] ge-([^ ]*)[^"]*("[^"]*")'
defines pattern to be catched, with two capturing groups (in round parentheses). Then matched string is replaced with string interface \1 name \2, where \1 and \2 are references to captured groups.